# Is this limiting function convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Lets look at the following set of functions $f_i$ defined as

$f_0 = n$

$f_1 = n \cdot log_{2}(n + 2)$

$f_2 = n \cdot log_{2}(n + 2) \cdot log_{2}(log_{2}(n + 4))$

$f_3 = n \cdot log_{2}(n + 2) \cdot log_{2}(log_{2}(n + 4)) \cdot log_{2}(log_{2}(log_{2}(n + 16)))$

$f_4 = n \cdot log_{2}(n + 2) \cdot log_{2}(log_{2}(n + 4)) \cdot log_{2}(log_{2}(log_{2}(n + 16))) \cdot log_{2}(log_{2}(log_{2}(log_{2}(n + 65536)))) $

...

$f_{k} = f_{k-1} \cdot log_2(log_2(... (n + 2\uparrow\uparrow k)))$ (where the log function was applied k times on the last term)

This sequence is approaching a limit

[image: graph of functions]

It is know that the $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f_i(k)}$  diverges (though ever more slowly) for each funtion $f_i$

I'm really curious to know what happens with the limit function?

Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f_\omega(k)}$ converge or diverge ?